# extract my java app with its database from netbeans

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have JAVA project with database in netbeans, I need to extract it to run without netbeans Like any Desktop Application 
can any one help me ?
noitce : I Had Used JPA in my application .

Comment: Try Install4j. It has 90 days evaluation period and is relatively user friendly. Plus there is ability to bundle JREs with the apps and end-user, the app looks like another Windows desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) which desrcibes how a jar file can be created from your NetBeans project. You can also create executables using the [packager tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) bundled with the JDK.